# How do I connect my 32 bit app to a 64 bit System DSN?

Tags: c#, dsn

How do I connect to a 64 bit system DSN from a 32 bit application? I get the error:
ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
con.ConnectionString = string.Format("DSN={0}", _dsnName);
```

I've seen lots of posts where people use 64 bit to connect to 32 is there a way to go from 32 to 64 without redefining your ODBC Connection using the 32 bit app?
c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: No. Also, DSNs are a nightmare and I would suggest avoiding their use entirely. IHMO you should try not to require users to make system changes in order to use your application.

Comment: What is the datasource you're trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

A 'prefer32bit' exe, calling a 64bit dll. 
Solutions:

1. [CorFlags.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool) SampleIntegration.exe /32BITPREF-
2. Untick 'prefer 32 bit' in VisualStudio
3. Compile to 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to you should consider compiling your app for Any CPU which will allow it to run as a 64 or 32 bit app depending on what HW it is run on.

For a very good detailed article about bitness differences see Scott Hanselman's [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx) about this.

Comment: There is an option for Prefer 32bit in Visual studio 2012, unchecking that defaults to 64 bit. Compiling it in 32 bit doesn't solve the problem, good guess though.